# VLC just shows a single picture of the webcam

Tags: raspberry-pi, webcam, vlc

I would like to show the live video of a Microsoft Studio webcam with a Raspberry Pi. It should be a reading tool for my grandma.

So I tried `vlc v4l2:///dev/video0` and I get always just a single picture. After that the system is frozen. You can just plug the power supply out.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? I also tried a smaller resolution.